# no warnings when component is created using const with typed def - ReactJS+Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I have following interface created for a component

```
interface FooProp {
  name: string;
  X: number;
  Y: number;
}
```

When I declare component using following code then I am get warnings If I don't pass all required props:

```
function Home(props: FooProp) {
  return <h1>Home</h1>
}
```

But when I use const to create component then I am not getting any warnings to pass required prop types:

```
const Home: React.FunctionComponent<FooProp> = (props: FooProp): React.ReactElement => {
  return <h1>Home</h1>
}
```

I am using ESLint. Is there any additional configuration needs to be done in order to show warnings for components created using ES6 syntax?

Comment: Well this wouldn't be an ES6 error, it would be a Typescript error.  Posting your above code into VS Code and doing `<Home/>`  I get this error -> `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'FooProp': name, X, Y`

Comment: @Keith did you ran `const Home: React.FunctionComponent<FooProp> `

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted your code above.  And this is using VS Code, using Typescript 3.8.3.   And yes, the FunctionComponet version, not the plain function version.